# SQL Server Schema to Schema Migration

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

I would like to know which one is the best approach for migrating existing DB data to another new DB with entirely different structure. I want to copy the data from my old DB and need to insert the data in new DB. For me the table names and column names of new DB is entirely different. I am using SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 1):

You should treat this as an ETL problem, not a migration, as the two schemas are entirely different. The proper tool for this is SSIS. SSIS allows you to create dataflows that map columns from one table to another, add derived sources, perform splits, merges, etc. If possible you should create source queries that return results close to the schema of the target database so you need fewer transformations.

Answer (score 0):

In this you have to migrate most of the parts manually by running scripts. AFAIK automatically it will not synchronize. But using SSMS you Map tables of two different db's. hope that will help.